# Is there any problem to remove all 1's in python?

Tags: python

```
data = [11,1,1,1,33,1,1,1,133,44,55]
for each in data:
    if each == 1:
        data.remove(1)
print(data)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[11, 33, 1, 1, 133, 44, 55]
```

Comment: Output should be `[11, 33, 133, 44, 55]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *avoid modifying an iterable while iterating*, since you're messing up the indexing.

Use list comprehensions to easily filter data:

```
[i for i in data if i!=1.]
# [11, 33, 133, 44, 55]
```

---

Or:

```
new_list = []
for each in data:
    if each != 1:
        new_list.append(each)
```

Comment: It can be done without using new_list?

Comment: I want to modify within the given list

Comment: Then try removing the elements from the list asyou where doing, but from end to beginning, that way changes in the index don't affect @nagalokesh

Comment: data = [11,1,1,1,33,1,1,1,133,44,55]
for each in data:
    if each == 1:
        data.remove(each)
print(data)

Comment: I tried but all 1's are not modified

Comment: output: [11, 33, 1, 1, 133, 44, 55]